# Front differential growling dodge dakota big horn 2010

Tags: dodge

Can the front driveshaft be removed, so the owner can still use the truck? will the transfer case leak fluid>?

Comment: Did you check the fluid levels in your differential? I'm not very familiar with this year of dodge, but I believe that you can safely remove a drive shaft as long as you make sure that the u-joint yokes stay in place on the transfer case and differential. These are necessary to hold the fluid inside.